# Django Tastypie and Django 1.4

Tags: django, api, integration, tastypie, django-1.4

If I want to integrate [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) with a project that I have already started in Django 1.4, will it work? If only partially, what are the implications? If not at all, that would be good to know before I start trying to integrate it. I would prefer, as well, to not have to rebuild the entire application in Django 1.5, and ideally will be able to add Tastypie to my existing 1.4 project.

Thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`django-tastypie==0.9.16` works correctly with Django 1.4.

Comment: I noticed that one of the listed requirements is Django 1.5. Have you used an older version with Django 1.4, or the current one?

Comment: The `0.9.16` version works fine with Django 1.4 - sorry for the typo